# Avoid scroll to content using Tabs with deep links in Foundation 6

Tags: tabs, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 6's tabs as described here: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/tabs.html

I want deep links, so I put the attribute data-deep-link=true. This works fine, but as the contents of the different tabs are of different length, the site jumps up and down when switching tabs.

Is there a way to allow deep linking without scrolling to content in Foundation 6?

(I read that this was possible with Foundation 5, with scroll_to_content: false, but I did not find any documentation about this with Foundation 6.)

To explain it a bit more, just with one tab entry:

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tabs data-deep-link="true" data-deep-link-smudge="true" data-update-history="true">
    <li class="tabs-title is-active">
        <a href="#jumpToTab">link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And below, the tab content container:

```
<div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="device-manager-tabs">
    <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="jumpToTab"></div>
</div>
```

From Browser's point of view, the jump to #jumpToTab is correct. But I would like to avoid it anyway, maintaining the functionality of Foundation. If Foundation would be able to use a custom attribute (such as `data-tab-id` instead of `id`, which is interpreted by browsers as well), it would be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `data-auto-focus="false"` to  your tab container.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it did not work. The Browser is still trying to jump to the selected anchor. Which is correct from the browser point of view, but I'd like the foundation functionality without jumping to the anchor, although I select it in the url.